# Let $f$ be defined by $|f(x)-f(y)| \geq |x-y|$ for every $x$ and $y$ from $[0,1]^2$ show that f is surjective

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, continuity

> Let $f$ be a continuous function such that
>
> $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$.
>
> is defined by $\lvert f(x)-f(y)\vert \geq \lvert x-y\rvert$ for every $x$ and $y$ from $[0,1]^2$. Show that $f$ is injective and find $f(0)$ and $f(1)$, then prove that $f$ is bijective.

To show that $f$ is injective

Let $x,y$ be in $[0,1]^2$

$f(x)=f(y)$ implies that $\lvert x-y\rvert \leq 0$ implies that $x=y$.

So $f$ is injective

Finding $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ I come to the fact that:

$$|f(0)-f(1)| \geq 1$$

$$|f(1)-f(0)| \geq 1.$$

Comment: Intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Its used that there is some c in (0,1) suck that $f(c)=0$ for example ? I usually use IVT in such questions like this

Comment: The title says $[0,1]^2$ while the question says both $(0,1)^2$ and $[0,1]^2$ in different places. Which one is it i.e. is the interval open or closed?

Comment: Since $f$ is continuous, image of $f$ is an interval containing 0 and 1 and hence $f$ is surjective.

Comment: The wording is incorrect. A function can only be defined by an inequality if, for whatever reason, that inequality implies an equality that actually defines $f$.

Comment: @Muralidharan Your argument works (only) if the function is assumed to be $[0,1] \to [0,1]$. But note that the body of the question defines $f : (0,1) \to (0,1)$ so values $\{0,1\}$ are not  even in its codomain, and $f(0), f(1)$ do not exist. I asked for clarification about $[0,1]$ vs. $(0,1)$ in my previous comment but the OP hasn't answered yet.

Comment: @dxiv I have edited the question ! I am in a frensh country ! We write $(a,b)$ as $]a,b[$ in my question $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ exists ! Its asked to find their values too

Comment: With the latest edit (and as hinted in previous comments) $|f(0) - f(1)| \ge 1$ means that $\{f(0), f(1)\} = \{0, 1\}$ and by IVT $f$ will take all values in between, so in the end $f([0,1])=[0,1]$.

Comment: @dxiv how could one find values of f(0) and f(1) ?

Comment: $|a-b| \le 1$ for all $0 \le a, b \le 1$ with equality occurring only when $a = 0, b = 1$ or $a = 1, b = 0$. Now let $a = f(0), b=f(1)$.